# Aumentar la longitud del eje Y - GGPLOT2

Tags: rstudio, ggplot2, dplyr

Tengo este problema (ver imagen):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quiero que el eje Y muestre todos los países y que las etiquetas no se superpongan. Estoy usando este código:

```
gapminder%>%
  group_by(country)%>%
  summarize(mean_life_expectancy=mean(life_expectancy))%>%
  arrange(desc(mean_life_expectancy))->lollipop
ggplot(lollipop,
       aes(x=mean_life_expectancy,
           y=reorder(country, mean_life_expectancy),
           color=mean_life_expectancy))+geom_point()

#Intenté esto:
axis_levels <- 
  lollipop %>%
  mutate(country = fct_inorder(country)) %>%
  pull(country) %>%
  .[seq(1, nlevels(.), length = 50)] %>%
  as.character()
ggplot(lollipop, aes(x=mean_life_expectancy, y=reorder(country, mean_life_expectancy))) +
  geom_point()+scale_x_discrete(breaks = axis_levels)
```

pero no me funcionó, ayuda por fa

Comment: Bienvenido Edwin  a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Lamentablemente con el Panel "Plots" no puedes hacer mucho, el gráfico se ajustará automáticamente para que se vea completo, el tema es que tu gráfico es más largo que ancho, por lo que no se va a ajustar adecuadamente en monitores que, al contrario, son más anchos que largos. Pero puedes hacer algunas cosas:

#### 1. Ajustar el tamaño de la letra

Hacer las etiquetas más chicas, al menos resolvería el tema de la superposición.

```
  + theme(
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 6)
  )
```

#### 2. Exportar el gráfico como una imagen

Aquí si podríamos ajustar la proporción y con alguna herramienta de visualización podríamos contar con barras de desplazamiento, luego de mostrar el gráfico puedes hacer:

```
ggsave("plot.png", width = 4, height = 9)
```

Los valores están en pulgadas, y el gráfico resultante es más alto que ancho.

#### 3. Usar `plotly`

Este paquete ofrece la función `ggplotly()` que transforma un gráfico `ggplot` en uno seminterctivo, dónde podrás jugar con el zoom, para ver adecuadamente las etiquetas, mediante el "zoom" a cierta área del grafico

```
library(plotly)

ggplot(lollipop,
       aes(x=mean_life_expectancy,
           y=reorder(country, mean_life_expectancy),
           color=mean_life_expectancy)) +
  geom_point() -> mi_plot

ggplotly(mi_plot)
```